# Display a Menu and Submenu as tabs

Tags: routes

I have a simple 2 level menu like this:

```
Category1
   Link1a
   Link1b
   Link1c
Category2
   Link2a
   Link2b
   Link2c
```

I'd like to create a tabbed Menu/Submenu for this: When Category1 or any of it's sublinks are selected (clicked) Category1 is "active" and its links are shown. Category2 is visible but its links are not:

[tabbed menu http://xooplate.com/assets/template/9845/p16qeq63ber8n2agm6hf8p2kb9-details.jpg](http://xooplate.com/assets/template/9845/p16qeq63ber8n2agm6hf8p2kb9-details.jpg)
(random example from the web)

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the quick tab module. It exactly do same thing.